# AVPlayer file requirements documentation

Tags: ios, ipad, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avplayeritem

I have an `AVPlayerLayer` which has an `AVPlayer` instantiated in my `init` method of its parent view controller. Everything works fine and as expected on Simulator and new devices, but on older iPad 2's and on iPod touch, the video does not play.

I saw in a seperate question someone saying that there was a 10MB file size limit on videos and expected resolutions for each device. My video was 2048x1536 and about 13 MB. I reduced it in size to 720p and it now works on my iPad 2.

What I need is the actual documentation on which devices support what size of files. I cannot find it for the life of me.

Comment: I would think that a device could not play a file with a larger resolution than what the screen permits. The iPad2 is 1024*720 which accounts for your 720p video working. Would it be as simple as querying the pixel resolution for your answer?

Comment: That'd be great if it were the case. iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus both work. I think iPhone 5S and 5 do as well. Video's resolution is already larger than all of those.